# Remove matching datasets

Tags: vba, excel

I have a sheet that lists data as follows:

```
|  A   |   B  |
|11111 |AAAAA |
|11111 |AAAAA |
|11111 |AAAAA |
|      |      |
|22222 |AAAAA |
|22222 |BBBBB |
|22222 |AAAAA |
|      |      |
|33333 |AAAAA |
|33333 |CCCCC |
|33333 |AAAAA |
|33333 |BBBBB |
```

The original data is not divided by blank rows. I wanted to divide the data into sets so I used the following macro to add a blank row whenever the value in Column A changes:

```
Sub InsertBlankRowWhenValueChanges()

Dim Rng As Range
Dim WorkRng As Range
On Error Resume Next
xTitleId = "Select Range"
    Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
    Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For i = WorkRng.Rows.Count To 2 Step -1
        If WorkRng.Cells(i, 1).Value <> WorkRng.Cells(i - 1, 1).Value Then
        WorkRng.Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Insert
        End If
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I need to somehow only keep the datasets that have changes in column B. If all of the data rows in column B match, the entire set can be removed.

Example:

REMOVE

```
|11111 |AAAAA |
|11111 |AAAAA |
|11111 |AAAAA |
```

KEEP

```
|22222 |AAAAA |
|22222 |BBBBB |
|22222 |AAAAA |
```

Is there anyway that this can be done?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Edit, nevermind, my initial thought wouldn't work & I have to take off.  It's definitely doable, just need to spend more time looking.  Sorry.

Comment: You can try to use countif function. If "countif(<range>,<first-cell-in-range>)" equals to number of cells in that range - means all are same.

Comment: Can you sort the data first? That would make it a bit quicker.

Comment: Simply add a third column, where you unite the first two columns. Then remove all non-uniques.

Comment: Why don't you also want to keep `|11111 |BBBBB `, and `33333 | CCCCC` and `33333 | BBBBB`? Edit: wait ...so you also want to edit data too? From your entire set of data you put at the top, *all* you want to keep is what's at the end, "KEEP"?

Comment: The data is sorted by the values in column A. There are multiple occurrences of the same value in column A, which I was referring to as sets. What I am looking for are ones where the value in column B changes within the set. In my example of an occurence I would like to remove, column A and B are the same values on each row. In the example I would want to keep, column B changes on one of the rows.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion @BruceWayne , I have updated the example to reflect what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you reworked your question, that makes more sense now...  Assuming your data looks like the following when you start, with the data starting in Row 1 (no column header):

```
|11111 |AAAAA|
|11111 |AAAAA|
|11111 |AAAAA|
|11111 |AAAAA|
|22222 |AAAAA|
|22222 |BBBBB|
|22222 |AAAAA|
|33333 |AAAAA|
|33333 |CCCCC|
|33333 |AAAAA|
|33333 |BBBBB|
```

The following would work:

```
Sub decideOnYourOwnNameForThis()

endRow = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

'setup formulas
Range("C2").Formula = "=IF(A2=A1,IF(B2<>B1,1,0), 0)"

'select the first formula row and copy
Range("C2").Select
Selection.Copy

'paste in the formulas
Range("C2:C" & endRow).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas

'destroy the forumulas
Range("C2:C" & endRow).Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

'fill up an array of col A values that you'd like to keep
Dim myArray() As String
aa = 1

For i = 2 To endRow
    If Cells(i, 3) = 1 Then
        ReDim Preserve myArray(1 To aa) As String
        myArray(aa) = Cells(i, 1)
        aa = aa + 1
    End If
Next i


'work backward and delete any row where col A is not contained in the array
For i = endRow To 1 Step -1

    boolContained = False
    For j = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)
        If Cells(i, 1) = myArray(j) Then
            boolContained = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next j

    If Not boolContained Then
        Rows(i & ":" & i).Select
        Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    End If

Next i

'remove the column if you don't want it
Columns("C:C").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft

End Sub
```

Finally, run your splitter code if you want the breaks, you can embed this before the End Sub above:

```
Call InsertBlankRowWhenValueChanges
```

Comment: Thank you @DavidPedack, but the only issue is I need to keep the entire dataset if there is a change. The macro is deleting every line except the line where there is a change. I am trying to eliminate the sets where every line is the same and keep the sets if there are any changes in column B.

Comment: Thank you @DavidPedack, it worked! I appreciate your time and help!